# Rewrite URL and pass a variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a PHP page: **site.com/page.php?city=variable**

I would like the URL to look like this: **site.com/your-city-variable**

My **.htaccess** has this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^your-city-([^/]+)/?$ page.php?city=$1
```

This works fine. The URL is rewritten and redirected. However the city variable is displayed as **City.php** on the page. (There is a .php extension appended to the city name) I would like the extension to not be appended to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I moved this line to the top of .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^your-city-([^/]+)/?$ page.php?city=$1
```